# Compile-time VS run-time

Tags: java, class, jar, collision

I've being having a trouble, i have a jar, that a partner created to read from a webservice implementing some wsdl handling, this was created in netbeans.

So I want to use this jar, when i use it, i get a `NoClassDefFoundError`, I think it happens because there are some library collission, so look at this from the stack trace:

```
NoClassDefFoundError org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.JAXWSHelper
[...]
org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:32)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
org.ubl.soap.test.SubmissionAPI.<init>(SubmissionAPI.java:44)
```

I'm using libraries from `javax.xml.ws` so it uses `Service.java`, so in that class in sometime it uses the class `javax.xml.ws.Provider`, but for some reason, it takes the same class in other library from `org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws`.

`org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws` comes from xfire.jar and javax.xml.ws comes from two jars i use in my project, one is axis2 and the other is jaxws-api.jar.

First thing that crossed my mind is if it's being taken the classes from axis2 instead of jaxws-api.jar then maybe the classes in axis2 aren't working as they are older, so if i wanna use the classes from jaxws-api.jar instead of the ones in axis2 what should i do ?

In the classpath, the two of them are defined, so the sames classes are defined, in different jars, but the namespaces are the same and i can't just remove axis2 cuz there is some of it the system is using...

so I know the error NoDefFoundClass is a run-time error, so maybe it's build correctly but in run-time is taking the classes from xfire instead of axis2...

Comment: Its called `NoClassDefFoundError` not `NoDefFoundClass`. Also please post the top of the Exception. The problem is that there is some class not found. The problem you write should never happen as you address classes by their FQN so, `javax.xml.ws.Provider` should not be addressed as `org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider`

Comment: Sorry your right, the top is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.JAXWSHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the javadoc of the `Provider` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.html#provider()

It says there:

> If a resource with the name of META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider exists, then its first line, if present, is used as the UTF-8 encoded name of the implementation class.

So, create that file and put the name of the Provider that you want to use into it.

The problem is that you call `Provider.provider()` and it returns the wrong one.

Comment: The problem is that org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.JAXWSHelper is not suppose to be used, the problem is the whole library shouldn't suppose to be used, notice i'm using classes from jaxws.xml.ws not from org.codehaus.xfire...

Comment: What i realized is the Provider class under javax.xml.ws is an interface, so in run time when it searches for an implementation of Provider class the one it finds is in org.codehaus.xfire, but what i'm wondering is how it works if i run it from netbeans..

Comment: @user2391243 You have to have a look into the sourcecode to see what class is actually intended to be called.

Comment: yes i looked, the line with it fails is this: delegate = Provider.provider().createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation,serviceName,this.getClass()); and is refering to the class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.java which looks to be an abstract class..

Comment: But for some reason there it takes org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.createServiceDelegate

Comment: @user2391243 I've looked up the API of your calls and found a solution, please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Yes i kind of realized that after reading the javadoc, thanks i gonna do it and tell you how it went...

Comment: Question what kind of file is that, a text file ? an xml file ? should i add this from netbeans then generate jar ?

Comment: @user2391243 its a textfile that contains one line. That line is the FQN of the desired Provider. You can create that wherever you want, Netbeans should act correctly.

Comment: It worked, i added the file inside META-INF i had to create the folder 'services' and inside of 'services' create a file named javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider with nothing inside, and it worked, thanks !!!!

Comment: @user2391243 Please mark the answer as correct then to complete this question. (the hook below the numbers on the left)